# CoreData Extremely Slow with Unique Constraints Enabled

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using Xcode 14.3 to develop an app targeting iOS 16.2. I have a CoreData 'Entity' that I want to enable unique constraints in order to allow merging of updated values.

```
// Overwrite with newer value if merge conflict
context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

[image]

The application downloads data from InfluxDB and successfully saves the data into CoreData without unique constraints enabled. However, with unique constraints, the database operations are extremely slow and I see the following type of print in the debug console every couple seconds, repeatedly.

```
CoreData: debug: PostSaveMaintenance: incremental_vacuum with freelist_count - 30 and pages_to_free 6
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the database extremely slow with these unique constraints enabled?

Comment: What’s the data type of the properties in the constraint list?

Comment: Both properties are Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that both constrained properties are strings. That's OK, but it's a lot of work for Core Data to verify uniqueness, especially if the strings are more than a few characters long. To ensure uniqueness, Core Data needs to compare two string values on a new instance to two string values on every instance that already exists. String comparisons are slow compared to numeric or date comparisons, and you're potentially doing *lots* of string comparisons every time you insert an object.

It might help if you create a fetch index for these properties. When you're editing the model, use Editor --> Add Fetch Index. That creates the index; then add these two properties to it.

If that's still too slow then you'll need to look at alternate ways of ensuring uniqueness. I don't know what values `time_string` has, but if it's a time of some kind then maybe add a numeric version of the property and use that for uniquing. Same for `satellite`-- I don't know what that is, but if you can use something numeric instead of a string, you'll get much faster results.